# How to pass error message to client from Web API controller's HttpPost async method returning Task<Type>?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

My Web API HttpPost method looks something like this

```
 [HttpPost("Data/{Customer}")]
    public async Task<DataSet> GetCustomerDataAsync(string CustomerID, [FromBody] QueryParameters[] parameters, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        return await GetCustomerData(CustomerID, parameters, ct);
    }
```

GetCustomerData runs a stored procedure that might RAISEERROR during parameter validations. The error is received as Error 500 (Internal Server Error) on the client side. I wonder how I can pass the stored procedure error message text to the client from the *GetCustomerDataAsync* method above?

Comment: Change the return type of the action to `IActionResult` to allow a more flexible response.

Comment: There's a bunch of other options detailed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the return type of the action to `IActionResult` to allow a more flexible response

```
[HttpPost("Data/{Customer}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomerDataAsync(string CustomerID, [FromBody] QueryParameters[] parameters, CancellationToken ct) {
    try {
        DataSet data = await GetCustomerData(CustomerID, parameters, ct);
        return Ok(data);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        //handle error (Logging?) and return appropriate response
        return StatusCode(500, new { error = "friendly_message_here" });
    }
}
```

If there is no exception thrown, the data is returned with a HTTP 200 OK. If an exception is thrown, you can return an appropriate response.

Reference [Controller action return types in ASP.NET Core Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types)